# Selenium is unable to drag and drop unless the action chain is ran twice (python)

Tags: python, selenium, drag-and-drop

I'm running into something strange with Selenium's action chain for drag and drop.

```
ActionChains(ctx.driver).click_and_hold(element_to_drag).move_by_offset(x_offset,y_offset).perform()
```

When I try to use it on a modal I have to run it twice for it to take effect:

```
ActionChains(ctx.driver).click_and_hold(element_to_drag).move_by_offset(x_offset,y_offset).perform()
ActionChains(ctx.driver).click_and_hold(element_to_drag).move_by_offset(x_offset,y_offset).perform()
```

I had the thought that perhaps the first action chain was somehow selecting the element and the second was dragging and dropping it so I replaced the first line with a click but that had no effect.  I also tried double clicking first, clicking and pausing, and click and hold but none of those had any effect.  The only way this works for me is to call it twice.  Has anyone ever experienced this or does anyone have some insight?  I'm running this on a mac.  I've read some comments online saying there were issues with drag and drop on macOS but those are all from several years ago. Also I'm using Selenium 3.141.0 with python 3.7.0.

Comment: you might want a release() in there, but click and drag in Selenium has always been a bit quirky, but you should also try using actions.drag_and_drop, or actions.drag_and_drop_by_offset instead.  The browser has to decide when it's a drag vs. a click and that can be a little complicated in itself.  For instance, you can click and drag and perform a click if your drag is small enough.  The browser has to decide based on where the release happens.

Comment: I couldn't get those to work for me at all.  When I call **drag_and_drop** or **drag_and_drop_by_offset**, I get a python error saying that the last argument was not sent.  That's what led me to use what I posted above (even though its just performing what is wrapped in drag_and_drop_by_offset).  Here's what I get using the same variables as above:
`ActionChains.drag_and_drop_by_offset(element_to_drag, x_offset, y_offset)`

`TypeError: drag_and_drop_by_offset() missing 1 required positional argument: 'yoffset'`